# Mysterious Margin?

Tags: html, css

I have been making a website in CSS and PHP, and the header seems to have a margin of about 2px between each link.
I didn't define this margin myself and can't find the cause of the problem anywhere.
I can sort of fix the issue by adding a negative margin of 2px but i feel that this doesn't really solve the problem and just masks it.

The links are inline-block's and before they were flush with each other and were inline with the "Leader Board" div i have.

[image: Margin between the Home and Login links]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px;
}

h2 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-size: cover;
}

#header {
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #ffbb00;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 90px;
}

#header h1 {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #00a1ff;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header a {
  padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: background .5s;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header a#selected {
  background: #ff9f00;
  cursor: default
}

#header a:hover {
  transition: background .5s;
  background: #ffaa00
}

#LeaderBoard {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 90px;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
  width: 492px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFEE77;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 9;
}

#LeaderBoardHead {
  background-color: #ffb233;
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#LeaderBoardHead h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 50;
  text-align: center;
}

#welcome {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 180px;
  margin-right: 45%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: ;
  z-index: 1;
}

#welcome h2 {
  font-size: 50;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #00a1ff;
}

#welcome h3 {
  color: #00a1ff;
  font-size: 22;
}

#welcome p {
  color: #00a1ff;
  font-size: 18;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Flash Crash</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/favicon.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css">

  <meta name="description" content="Flash Crash" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">

      <h1>Flash Crash</h1>

      <a id="selected" href="../index.php" hreflang="en-gb">Home</a> <a href="../login.php" hreflang="en-gb">Login</a> <a href="../feedback.php" hreflang="en-gb">Feedback</a> </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/LeaderBoard.css" />

    <div id="LeaderBoard">

      <div id="LeaderBoardHead">
        <h2>Leader Board</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="LeaderBoardContent">

      </div>

    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/welcome.css" />

    <div id="welcome">
      <h2>Welcome to Flash Crash!</h2>
      <h3>The Online Flash Card Crash Course for Computer Science</h3>
      <p>Flash Crash is a competitive online revision tool for computing students. <br> compete against your class mates by compleeting randomly generated quizzes <br> to earn points and unlock new editing permissions on the site!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's My website so you can see the problem for yourself:

[jakehowell.me](http://jakehowell.me/)

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Please put this code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), so that others can easily debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces between you menu `a` tags. If you remove those, it works as expected.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px;
}

h2 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-size: cover;
}

#header {
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #ffbb00;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 90px;
}

#header h1 {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #00a1ff;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header a {
  padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: background .5s;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header a#selected {
  background: #ff9f00;
  cursor: default
}

#header a:hover {
  transition: background .5s;
  background: #ffaa00
}

#LeaderBoard {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 90px;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
  width: 492px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFEE77;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 9;
}

#LeaderBoardHead {
  background-color: #ffb233;
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#LeaderBoardHead h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 50;
  text-align: center;
}

#welcome {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 180px;
  margin-right: 45%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: ;
  z-index: 1;
}

#welcome h2 {
  font-size: 50;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #00a1ff;
}

#welcome h3 {
  color: #00a1ff;
  font-size: 22;
}

#welcome p {
  color: #00a1ff;
  font-size: 18;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Flash Crash</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/favicon.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css">

  <meta name="description" content="Flash Crash" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">

      <h1>Flash Crash</h1>

      <a id="selected" href="../index.php" hreflang="en-gb">Home</a><a href="../login.php" hreflang="en-gb">Login</a><a href="../feedback.php" hreflang="en-gb">Feedback</a></div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/LeaderBoard.css" />

    <div id="LeaderBoard">

      <div id="LeaderBoardHead">
        <h2>Leader Board</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="LeaderBoardContent">

      </div>

    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/welcome.css" />

    <div id="welcome">
      <h2>Welcome to Flash Crash!</h2>
      <h3>The Online Flash Card Crash Course for Computer Science</h3>
      <p>Flash Crash is a competitive online revision tool for computing students. <br> compete against your class mates by compleeting randomly generated quizzes <br> to earn points and unlock new editing permissions on the site!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are whiteSpace text nodes presented between anchor tags.Inpect the anchor tags you will find small bubble between anchor tags.
See this link .you will find answer
https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/

Answer (score 0):

It's a known problem with white-space.
You can remove the spaces between your links or float them next to eachother to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **margin:0px;** in every element, you could use:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
 }
```

* Is used for applying whatever you put there on everything